# Why are the ice packs always blue

Tags: psychologist-psychology, environmental-psychology

I read it in the book Peter Atkins

> The endothermic dissolution of ammonium nitrate in water is the basis of the instant cold-packs that are included in some first-aid kits. They consist of a plastic envelope containing water dyed blue (for psychological reasons) and a small tube of ammonium nitrate, which is broken when the pack is to be used.

Could not understand why die water blue would have any physiological effect on a body. What type of physiological effect is he refering to?

Comment: The quoted part says *psych*ological.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't want it dyed blood red though!

But seriously, from:

> [Very Well Mind](https://www.verywellmind.com/the-color-psychology-of-blue-2795815)

we have:

> Blue is a color often found in nature such as the pale blue of a daytime sky or the rich dark blue of a deep pool of water. It is for this reason perhaps that people often describe the color blue as calm and serene. Yet as a cool color, blue can sometimes seem icy, distant, or even cold.

and

> Blue calls to mind feelings of calmness or serenity. It is often described as peaceful, tranquil, secure, and orderly.

and

> Blue is often seen as a sign of stability and reliability. Businesses that want to project an image of security often utilize blue in their advertising and marketing efforts.

[Color Psychology](https://www.colorpsychology.org/blue/) agrees with this view of blue.